# Relationships and Dashboard are broken with https

Tags: relationships, dashboard

I recently tried forcing https in the htaccess file and noticed that the relationships in the main contact screen disappeared.  They show up if I access them through a listing on the dashboard, but if I access the record through search they are simply not listed.  Also the dashboard doesn't display properly and can't be configured.  I haven't noticed other effects of https but they may exist too.

Comment: Might be helpful for you to tell us exactly how you went about forcing https. It's generally better to do that in a virtual host file (assuming apache server). I would also try @laryn's answer first as your baseurl may be incorrect now.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing I'd check is whether your `CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL` in `civicrm.settings.php` is set without the `https` and if so, change that. Then flush caches and test again.

Comment: There is no CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL setting in my civicrm.settings.php file.

Comment: And, in fact, the only configuration file I could find was civicrm.config.php (not civicrm.settings.php.  Is that file located somewhere else or should I have a BASEURL statement in the config file?

Comment: Which CMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Drupal

Comment: Look in `sites/default/` for the `civicrm.settings.php` file.